# Create a heredoc that doesn't interpret anything

Tags: linux, bash, heredoc

I'm writing a script for a friend who is not experienced with bash. The script generates a backup script, generates a crontab and runs crontab to create a cron job.

I want to date these backups, so currently the script (what's relevant) is:

```
cat <<EOF > ~/scheduledBackups/scripts/finalCutScript.bash
mkdir -p ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-`date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H`
cp -r $BACKUP_DIR/* ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-`date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H`
EOF
```

This, however, generates `finalCutScript.bash` with the date as is when the "installer" script is run.

Is there a way to place exactly that heredoc within `finalCutScript.bash`? I want to keep everything in one script so that I can use this script framework later.

### Elaboration

Expected behaviour:

I want the file that the heredoc is piped into to contain

```
mkdir -p ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-`date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H`
cp -r $BACKUP_DIR/* ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-`date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H`
```

Actual behaviour

The file generated by that heredoc contains

```
mkdir -p ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-Fri-Aug-05-2016_16
cp -r ~/Documents//* ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-Fri-Aug-05-2016_16
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should `EOF` in heredoc and use `$(...)` for command substitution:

```
cat <<-'EOF' >~/scheduledBackups/scripts/finalCutScript.bash
mkdir -p ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-$(date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H)
cp -r $BACKUP_DIR/* ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-$(date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H)
EOF
```

---

**Update:** As per OP's comment below you can also escape `$` for not expanding a variable in current shell:

```
BACKUP_DIR='foobar' # variable to be used below in here-doc

cat <<-EOF >~/scheduledBackups/scripts/finalCutScript.bash
mkdir -p ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-\$(date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H)
cp -r $BACKUP_DIR/* ~/scheduledBackups/FinalCut-\$(date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H)
EOF
```

Above command will use `$BACKUP_DIR` from your current environment but will add literal `$(date +%a-%b-%d-%Y_%H)` in the output.

Comment: I don't want command substitution. I want to write to finalCutScript.bash so that command substitution happens there.

Comment: You need to quote the heredoc terminator in the redirection, so variable/command substitution is NOT permformed: `cat <<-'EOF'` as demonstrated -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Comment: Note that the answer combines two special cases.  The notation `<<-word` means 'drop leading tabs from the contents of the here document.  The notation `<<'EOF'` with quotes around the word (double quotes or a backslash are also options) means 'do not interpret the contents of the heredoc'.  And the combination `<<-'EOF'` means "don't interpret and do strip leading tabs".  Note that tab removal is strictly for tabs, not other white space.  Beware: Bash may have extensions over other shells.

Comment: I just tested, and it worked. I didn't realize that <<-'EOF' made a difference. @JonathanLeffler thanks for the explanation of how it works.

Comment: Update on this - using `<<-'EOF'`, is there any way to do variable substitution? I need to temprarily re-enable bash interpreting to place a variable in the heredoc `${...}` doesn't seem to work

Comment: For variable substitution you will need to go back to `cat <<EOF` (see updated answer)